# How I define a function in Python to convert object columns into floats?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, user-defined-functions

I imported a DataFrame that has columns of different types. See below:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1272 entries, 0 to 1271
Columns: 189 entries, Year to HUMAN_rank
dtypes: float64(67), int64(1), object(121)
memory usage: 1.8+ MB
```

I would like to come up with a function that iterates over each column of the DataFrame, identifies the type of value in each column, and converts it into a float if the column has type object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To only do this for `object` dtypes, you could do this using [`select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
df[df.select_dtypes('object').columns] = df.select_dtypes('object').astype(float)
```

For example:

```
>>> df
  col1      col2 col3  col4
0    1  0.452893    2     8
1    2  0.745232    3     6
2    1  0.374296    3     1
3    3  0.398660    3     4
4    2  0.902737    2     1
5    3  0.940392    3     0
6    3  0.382493    3     0
7    2  0.684829    3     4
8    2  0.506248    3     8
9    1  0.161701    3     3

>>> df.dtypes
col1     object
col2    float64
col3     object
col4      int64
dtype: object

>>> df[df.select_dtypes('object').columns] = df.select_dtypes('object').astype(float)

>>> df.dtypes
col1    float64
col2    float64
col3    float64
col4      int64
dtype: object
```

**Note**: if some of your columns have some values that can't be converted to float, the method above won't work. You could iterate through them, convert them using `pd.to_numeric` with `errors='coerce'` and `downcast='float'`:

```
>>> df
  col1      col2 col3  col4
0    3  0.594651    2     6
1    3  0.677595    3     3
2    3  0.546434    1     0
3    3  0.454769    2     6
4    x  0.321130    2     3
5    2  0.473391    2     7
6    1  0.207182    2     7
7    2  0.883071    3     1
8    x  0.994372    2     4
9    1  0.052539    3     2

>>> df.dtypes
col1     object
col2    float64
col3     object
col4      int64
dtype: object

for col in df.select_dtypes('object').columns:
    df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors='coerce', downcast='float')

>>> df
   col1      col2  col3  col4
0   3.0  0.594651   2.0     6
1   3.0  0.677595   3.0     3
2   3.0  0.546434   1.0     0
3   3.0  0.454769   2.0     6
4   NaN  0.321130   2.0     3
5   2.0  0.473391   2.0     7
6   1.0  0.207182   2.0     7
7   2.0  0.883071   3.0     1
8   NaN  0.994372   2.0     4
9   1.0  0.052539   3.0     2
>>> df.dtypes
col1    float32
col2    float64
col3    float32
col4      int64
dtype: object
```